# Eliminating Dandelion with concentrated vinegar solution

Tags: lawn, weeds

I have serious infestation of dandelion this spring, and to kill it, I bought the 30% vinegar solution from Green Gobbler.

I used undiluted 30% solution and put it in the multipurpose sprayer, setting a nozzle to squirt rather than spraying so that I can shoot vinegar solution right on the top of dandelion to minimize vinegar spreading immediate adjacent lawn. I probably squirted a good 5ml or slightly more and it killed dandelion and surrounding lawn as seen in the following photo;

[image: squirt spot]

I probably squired a way too much and should diluted the vinegar solution down.

Question: Will the surrounding dead grass grow back eventually ?

Also;  I've experimented  with a few dilutions but have not found a sweat spot in which dilution of the vinegar is enough to kill dandelion but has less damage on adjacent lawn.

I'd appreciate any comments or pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the question is; Is there a dilution that will kill the dandelions but not kill the grass ?

Comment: I'd suggest you try this question at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Dandelion makes good salad... that would have caused less damage :)

Comment: According to this answer there is a fair chance the roots of your grass and the dandelion survived: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9495/how-do-i-fix-an-area-of-grass-that-was-ruined-using-a-vinegar-salt-treatment-of/9497#9497

Comment: @SolarMike Oil and vinegar, MMMM. Pull em up by the roots before they seed.

Comment: @AlaskaMan dandelion -> dent de lion -> piss en lit ...

Comment: I gather you don't want to hear this, but plain old 2,4-D is one of the oldest and most tested and understood herbicides in history  Rejecting 2,4-D because "icky, sorcerer's apprentice, science unknown consequences FUD blah blah" is like rejecting traditional hybrid corn because GMOs are bad.  On the other hand, speaking of sorcerer's apprentice, any such product is not for moro-- well, let's just say you need to apply the stuff competently and MUST follow directions, that's Federal law.

Comment: `Will the surrounding dead grass grow back eventually ?` .... 2000 years is eventually ..... anyway, the grass will grow back fairly quickly

Comment: You guys think this is funny. Well,  I've let  dandelion slip through fingers a way too long and guess what happens. It literately has  proliferated 100 fold in a few days, and my neighbors are complaining.  After vinegar, I was gonna dig and pull the roots but there were so many.   I guess I have to resort on the nuclear option....